# log4j debug is not working in Jboss 7.1

Tags: java, jboss, log4j, jboss7.x

I have Enterprise Java Project with Jboss 7.1.

I've added log4j for my EAR.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

now , logger.error() works well.  but logger.debug is not working. What do you think about this?.. how to enable debug?

```
@Startup 
@Stateless
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class MyClass{

    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getSimpleName());

    @PostConstruct
    private void invoke() {
           logger.error("error ");
       logger.debug("debug");
        }
}
```

Comment: EJB tag has no significance here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jboss has it's own binder which can not be overridden runtime, pls ensure you have added log4j.properties with proper debug level. try to use fileappender in it so that you will come to whether Jboss is using your log4j binder or it's own.

Comment: BasicConfigurator.configure() method makes default configuration  with log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG. I have added this method but it doesnot work yet




    log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CA


i've add BasicConfigurator.configure() but it does not work yet.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't log4j ships log4j jars? For configuration check with your standalone.xml or configuration file which you are using.

Search for logging subsystem,

e.g.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
```

Set the root-logger level name to FINER as sampled below, rerun and check:

```
        <root-logger>
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
```

How to add appenders?

Say you are initializing Logger object for class ABC in package x.y.z, using,

```
Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ABC.class);
```

So the appender for the same will look like something:

```
        <logger category="x.y.z">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
```

or

```
        <logger category="x.y">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
```

or

```
        <logger category="x">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
```

Depends on the level of granularity you want.

Comment: How are you doing the logging can you try to explain in your question, mention details like config file, loading log4j config. Using your own jars or jars shipped with jboss

Comment: I did not have any config. I use Jboss defautl configuration. then I write BasicConfigurator.configure()  befro logger.debug() in order to create default configuration. I saw this example here: http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/log4j/sample-log4j-properties-file-configuration-1.html

Comment: should I add some another configuration. is it importance?

Comment: No you should not,  if you are using an enterprise server, I would like to use the maximum I can get out of it. If you are using the same configuration, then you just need to set appenders and you are ready to roll.

Comment: but what should I do now?  I did not understand.. I change <level name="DEBUG"/> and it still does not work. it was set   <level name="INFO"/>  and it works. I changed but.... how can I set All the names?

Comment: See my updated answer, do share how you are starting the JBoss server.

Comment: Mark as answer so can be closed.